# Checking for presence of keys in GitLab-CI with jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, gitlab, jq

I am trying to analyze a variable in the GitLab-CI to see if there are two keys and if a value has a certain value.

My current one looks like this:

```bash
if [[ $(echo $TRIGGER_PAYLOAD | jq -e '.changes.title.previous and .changes.title.current and .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"') ]]; then
    echo 'Do something'
fi
```

I have already tried many things, including select(), but now I don't know what to do.

---

I just created an minimal example for this:

```bash
set -x
payload="{\"object_attributes\": {\"detailed_merge_status\": \"draft_status\"},\"changes\": {}}"
echo $(echo $payload | jq -r .)

if jq -e '.changes.title.previous and .changes.title.current and .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"' <<<"$payload"; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

This one works, also vice versa works:

```bash
set -x
payload="{\"changes\": {\"title\": {\"previous\": \"test\", \"current\": \"test\"}},\"object_attributes\": {\"detailed_merge_status\": \"mergeable\"}}"
echo $(echo $payload | jq -r .)

if jq -e '.changes.title.previous and .changes.title.current and .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"' <<<"$payload"; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

If I now use the real payload instead of the dummy JSON, it doesn't work again. Whereas a simple query with jq on .key.key works with all values.

```
$ if jq -e '.changes.title.previous and .changes.title.current and .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"' <<<"$TRIGGER_PAYLOAD"; then # collapsed multi-line command
++ echo '$ if jq -e '\''.changes.title.previous and .changes.title.current and .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"'\'' <<<"$TRIGGER_PAYLOAD"; then # collapsed multi-line command'
++ jq -e '.changes.title.previous and .changes.title.current and .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
++ echo false
false
```

Comment: For one, `echo $anything` is buggy; **always** `echo "$anything"` with the quotes (or even better, use `printf '%s\n' "$variable"`) to avoid the bugs described in [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: And you don't need/shouldn't use `[[` if you're using `jq -e` to have jq set exit status; you can just `if jq -e '...' <<<"$payload"; then` (notice lower-case -- all-caps is the namespace used by variables meaningful to the shell itself; names you define yourself should have at least one lower-case character to stay out of that space).

Comment: But we can't tell for sure if either of those things are your immediate problem without more details about _exactly_ what's going wrong. (Use `set -x` to get logging of the actual values in use, and pay attention to whether stderr is passing out an error message from jq; error messages, sample input &c need to be _included in the question itself_ to constitute a proper [mre])

Comment: (to explain the printf-vs-echo advice, see the answer to the [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) -- especially if you don't know which shell your CI process runs with, its `echo` may be different than yours -- bash's `echo` is slightly noncompliant with POSIX by default (a strictly conformant one will make `echo -e` print `-e` on output); containers often use sh implementations without those problems).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I just updated the original question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Would `jq -n '$ENV.TRIGGER_PAYLOAD | ...'` also work here?

Comment: @rickhg12hs `jq -n --argjson j '$ENV.TRIGGER_PAYLOAD" '$j | (.)'`. It would save a pipe and sub-shell. It is safer to assign the JSON to a Jq variable rather than throw it as a filter which might interpret content as commands though.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, it'd need to be exported, but good call in general on use of `-n` and `$ENV`. (I'd still want `-e` so jq can set its own exit status, and... why are we piping from jq at all?)

Comment: (The answer by LéaGris looks great to me -- so while I do appreciate your updates to the question, I'm going to step out now unless you comment back and indicate that there's something more to be added).

Answer (score 2):

When testing the return status of a command, you don't use the bracket test but the command directly (*1).

Here is how you could perform your test:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Testing data
triggerPayload='
{
  "changes": {
    "title": {
      "previous": "test",
      "current": "test"
    }
  },
  "object_attributes": {
    "detailed_merge_status": "mergeable"
  }
}
'

# shellcheck disable=SC2016 # Does not expand shell expressions
jqFilter='
$j | (
  .changes.title.previous and
  .changes.title.current and
  .object_attributes.detailed_merge_status == "mergeable"
)'

if jq --exit-status --null-input --argjson j "$triggerPayload" "$jqFilter" >/dev/null; then
    echo 'Do something'
fi
```

---

**Notes:**

1. The `[` or `[[` is actually a shell command, that takes testing arguments where the last one must be `]` or `]]` respectively.